# Setting and Access Cookies from Main Domain to Sub-Domain

Tags: javascript, php, cookies

I got  a peculiar situation and spent lots of time in investigating but could not success.

I have a domain like www.A where on home page I'm running a Javascript to access a PHP script from another subdomain dev.A. This PHP script needs to set a cookie and then I want to access same cookie in another script which I'm accessing again under www.A.

Kindly help in achieving this.
Regards
Mohtashim

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set the cookie in a domain and make sure it's available on every sub-domain you should use the domain (without the `www` subdomain) in the `setcookie` function:

```
setcookie('cookie_name', 'cookie_value' , 0 , "" , 'yourdomain.com');
                                       // ^       This is the expiring time of the cookie
                                       //     ^   This is the path of the cookie
```

This will allow your subdmains (both `www.A` and `dev.A`) to access that cookie.

[Read more here](http://php.net/set_cookie) about all the parameters of the `setcookie` function.

Comment: Thanks Dekel for your quick response. Here I want to set cookie in sub-domain and then want to access it in main domain.

Comment: Do I also need to set something in my Ajax call as well??

Comment: Not that I can think of

Comment: Are you sure you set the cookie correctly? Do you get the cookie on the browser? (can you share a link to check?P

Comment: Another option - try using `.yourdomain.com` (add a dot at the beginning).

Comment: Sir, I shared my solution which is working fine now. Thank you very much for your kind support.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got a solution where I needed to fix my Ajax call to add the following:

```
crossDomain: true,
xhrFields: {
  withCredentials: true
},
```

But then it started giving me issue related to Access-Control-Allow-Origin because in my httpd.conf it was set to *, so I commented that out but still it did not resolve the issue, then I added following two lines in my PHP scripts which were setting session and reading sessions:

```
   header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://www.example.com");
   header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials : true");
```

Finally, after spending whole night now I'm able to use my session in a sub-domain. Hope this will help someone.